# Filter RadGrid content by multiple criteria by one action

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to optimize the way RadGrid filtering works for me. For example, I want to filter content by several columns, but don't want to apply filter to each of them one-by-one. I always use "Contains" filter, nothing else. So, I want just to input search criteria into several columns and do something to get all of them applied after postback. Do we have an ability of doing such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to perform this

1- You can use filtering with **RadFilter** for Rad Grid if this will be suitable to your client.

Please check more on [this telerik demos](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/filter/examples/integration/defaultcs.aspx?product=grid).

2- Disable default grid filtering and add your custom textboxes for columns you need to filter with in the grid **CommandItemTemplate** and add a "Search" button. In this case user will enter all search data then click on "Search" button to filter the grid.

For more information, please check [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/webmailgrid/defaultcs.aspx) and [this telerik help post](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-search-on-key-press.html)